# Why is my React component unable to pick up the library I am requiring?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar.io in my React project.

I've installed it using `npm install fullcalendar`.

I see `node_modules/fullcalendar` in my directory.

In my project, I am using:

`var Scheduler = require('fullcalendar');`

I then have:

```
var Calendar = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id='calendar'>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Yet I am receiving this error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`.

(Side note - requiring other modules works fine. I can do `var moment = require('moment')` and then a `console.log(moment())` and it outputs a new moment variable.)

Comment: di you have jquery `$` as a module?

Comment: Very odd. I haven't had to require jquery yet, and previous jquery functions worked fine - I just tested it (it is in my index file). And yet, adding `var $ = require('jquery')` allowed fullCalendar to launch. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to require all the libraries that need to kick in in each Component. Just having it in your index file for files that need to get transformed/bundled won't work. (it's kind of sad to need to use jQuery in a React application, since jQuery is for overcoming the problem of not knowing where/what your elements are, whereas in React you **always** know what your elements are)

Comment: I'll be sure to do this in the future. I'm still confused though, since I was able to hide components using jQuery (not that I did, but I was able to) without requiring the module first. Anyway, yeah it is a bit sad to use jQuery but I need it for FullCalendar!

Comment: once the site's loaded, any unscoped jquery would run just fine, but it'll also conflict with how React rerenders (any jquery changes get wiped if the React component's props or state are updated). As for needing jQuery for FullCalendar, surely there's a non-jquery calendar solution? https://github.com/react-component/calendar for instance?

Comment: Very nice calendar there but we are using the scheduling aspect of FullCalendar - with drag and drop options for events.